# Why JSON.parse() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, json

How is possible that this code:

```
this.store.select(getAuthResponseSelector)
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticateResponse) => {
            if (response != null) {
                console.log('Response', response);
                console.log('ResponseType', typeof response);
                console.log('EntroSubscribeTokenBefore', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
                console.log('EntroSubscribeTokenType', typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
                console.log('EntroSubscribeToken', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).access_token);
                const newToken = Object.assign({}, response);
                console.log('NewObject', typeof newToken);
                for(let key in newToken){
                    console.log('Key:', newToken[key])
                }
                this.token = newToken.access_token
            }
        });
```

Prints this output:

```
[12:32:39]  console.log: Response
            {"access_token":"afcddc76-8322-4186-9b54-aa4143f381eb","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"fda3fcf4-8335-45cf-94ca-cd0aec1a90cb","expires_in":26313,"scope":"custom
            default","firstname":"testswinetmm_cost","lastname":"testswinetmm_cost","email":"testswinetmm_cost@testingmail.com","uid":"testswinetmm_cost"}
[12:32:39]  console.log: ResponseType string
[12:32:39]  console.log: EntroSubscribeTokenBefore
            {"access_token":"afcddc76-8322-4186-9b54-aa4143f381eb","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"fda3fcf4-8335-45cf-94ca-cd0aec1a90cb","expires_in":26313,"scope":"custom
            default","firstname":"testswinetmm_cost","lastname":"testswinetmm_cost","email":"testswinetmm_cost@testingmail.com","uid":"testswinetmm_cost"}
[12:32:39]  console.log: EntroSubscribeTokenType string
[12:32:39]  console.log: EntroSubscribeToken
[12:32:39]  console.log: NewObject object
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: {
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: "
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: a
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: c
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: c
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: e
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: s
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: s
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: _
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: t
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: o
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: k
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: e
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: n
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: "
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: :
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: "
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: a
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: f
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: c
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: d
[12:32:39]  console.log: Key: d
...
```

The response object have a custom type(an object in any case) but trying to convert it to get a JSON object I get this result, could anybody explain me how is this possible??

**UPDATE**

Even when stringifiying an string which could make an error. The last part when I create a new object with `Object.asssign()` I print the type and its tell me that is an object, but when iterating its properties it print each letter as a String, that should not happend I think

**UPDATE 2**
I also know that JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) has no sense in this case, I have tried this because based on the response that I expect and what I really recieve doesnt make sense, that is why I was trying various conversions.

P.D: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) is not that weird, is commonly used to create deep copy of a JSON object :)

Comment: This question is very confusing

Comment: could you please , paste the response from the server , i wonder why are stringify and parse it again?

Comment: if you can console.log(response) and let me know what you are getting.

Comment: `newToken` is an object e.g. (`{key: "{\"access_token\":\"af"}`). `newToken[key]` is a string (`"{\"access_token\":\"af"`). If you iterate over a string you will receive each character.

Answer (score 3):

It must be because your `response` is a string and not an object. So `JSON.stringify` creates JSON string from string and then `JSON.parse` parses that JSON string to normal string.

Edit:

You know that even if you use  `response: AuthenticateResponse` in TypeScript, `response` might not be that type? Your `response` is clealy type of string containing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that `response` is a string and therefore you need to parse it with JSON.parse() before you can use it properly. What is happening now is that you're iterating over a string, and a loop over a string will print each character from the string.

I suspect that something like this is what you really wanted to happen (note the use of JSON.parse(), and also Object.assign() is redundant in this scenario):

```js
var response = '{"access_token":"afcddc76-8322-4186-9b54-aa4143f381eb","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"fda3fcf4-8335-45cf-94ca-cd0aec1a90cb","expires_in":29605,"scope":"custom default","firstname":"testswinetmm_cost","lastname":"testswinetmm_cost","email":"testswinetmm_cost@testingmail.com","uid":"testswinetmm_cost"}';
const newToken = JSON.parse(response);

for(let key in newToken){
   console.log(key, ":", newToken[key])
}
```

---

P.S. In your Console. logs `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))` makes no sense at all. - if you do that, you just get out exactly what you put in, because parsing is the exact opposite of stringifying - you only need parse() if you've got a string you want to turn into an object, and you only need stringify() if you've got an object you want to turn into a string. You never need both at once. Possibly this was adding to your confusion, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('EntroSubscribeTokenType', typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
```

> [11:37:46]  console.log: EntroSubscribeTokenType string

This means that `response` is actually a string.

```js
const json = '{ "name" : "Fred" }';
console.log(typeof json, json);

const jsonToString = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(typeof jsonToString, jsonToString);

const jsonToStringParsed = JSON.parse(jsonToString);
console.log(typeof jsonToStringParsed, jsonToStringParsed);

console.log("json === jsonToStringParsed", json === jsonToStringParsed);
```

So when you come to the part when you try to make a new object, you are actually working with a *string*. Therefore, `Object.assign` will give you something you probably don't expect:

```js
const response = '{ "name" : "Fred" }';

const newToken = Object.assign({}, response);

console.log(typeof newToken);
console.log(newToken);
```

It's actually a new object from the string, so the key-value pairs are the indexes and the associated characters to them. This is because the string primitive is turned into a String *object* for the copy to take place

```js
const stringObject = new String( '{ "name" : "Fred" }');

console.log("typeof stringObject:", typeof stringObject);
console.log("stringObject instanceof String:", stringObject instanceof String);
console.log(stringObject);
```

Therefore, when you iterate over a `newToken` it's an object representation of a String object representation of a string.

```js
const response = '{ "name" : "Fred" }';

const newToken = Object.assign({}, response);

for (let key in newToken) {
  console.log("key -> valye:", key, newToken[key])
}
```

As a final note, `Object.assign()` will NOT create a new copy of the String object - you actually get a plain object because the prototype is not copied over:

```js
const string = '{ "name" : "Fred" }';
const stringObject = new String(string);

const newTokenFromString = Object.assign({}, string);
const newTokenFromStringObject = Object.assign({}, stringObject);

//false - because it's a string primitive
console.log("string instanceof String:", string instanceof String);
//true
console.log("stringObject instanceof String:", stringObject instanceof String);
//false - it's an object, not an instance of String
console.log("newTokenFromString instanceof String:", newTokenFromString instanceof String);
//false - it's an object, not an instance of String
console.log("newTokenFromStringObject instanceof String:", newTokenFromStringObject instanceof String);
```

Answer (score -4):

You are getting response in Object format. To check whether syntax of JSON data is valid or not , you can copy the response text to online JSON parser like [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser).